# Lambda Calculus - reduction with a shorthand term

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm new to lambda calculus and am having trouble understand how a shorthand acts when reducing.

Given:
$((\lambda xy.x)(\lambda y.y))y$

What I have:

since $\lambda xy.x = \lambda x.\lambda y.x$

$((\lambda x.\lambda y.x)(\lambda y.y))y$

Now from here, I'm not sure how to continue with the reduction.
I believe the whole thing is supposed to simplify to $xy$ but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: There is a typo, in the last lamda expression it should be ((Lx.Ly.x)(Ly.y))y.

Comment: @6005 Thanks, fixed it

Comment: After simplifying, I get $\lambda y. y$, not $xy$.

Comment: @6005  

is this the proper steps?
((Lx.Ly.x)(Ly.y))y
= (Ly.(Ly.y)) y
= (Ly.y)

Comment: No you have to do a variable change before the first application, because there are two Lys.

Comment: Ah gotcha. With variable changes you're allowed to use any variable name right?
So it could be
((Lx.Ly.x)(Ly.y))y
= ((Lx.Lw.x)(Ly.y)y
= (Lw.(Ly.y))y
= Ly.y

Comment: Yep! Now you got it.

Comment: @6005 awesome thanks so much!